# Htaccess debug alternate rules for rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu

I need to parse one or two variables within /a/ "folder".  In the past we only needed the one for assoc.  Now I need to parse assoc/state separately WHEN someone uses state (it will be only 10% of use cases, so I need to support both use cases).

Example
1: domain.com/a/joe = domain.com/?assoc=joe
2: domain.com/a/joe/ohio = domain.com/?assoc=joe&state=ohio

The following is the first few lines of my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ / [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)$ https://%1/?assoc=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)/(.*)$ https://%1/?assoc=$1&state=$2 [L]
```

I can get either line to work on its own (for the respective use case):

```
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)$ https://%1/?assoc=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^a/(.*)/(.*)$ https://%1/?assoc=$1&state=$2 [L]
```

But with both lines it always parses the first line and I get;
domain.com/?assoc=joe/ohio  (as one variable only)

Any help on what I am missing here. How do I get htaccess to skip the first option when I have more than one variable?

Comment: The pattern `^a/(.*)$` matches on `a/joe/ohio` as well. Reverse the _order_ of the two rules ...

Comment: No, reversing the order just breaks it for users who do example 1: domain.com/a/joe = domain.com/?assoc=joe

Comment: error is ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT